# How to reference dist/js files from mvc view index.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have combined a CLI generated Vue application with ASP.NET Core web application.

I want to create a new entry point and use this new entry point in the MVC view while not impacting the existing main.js entry point.

I am using the following vue.config.js file to add the second entry point.

// https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages

```
module.exports = {
    pages: {
        index: {
            // entry for the page
            entry: 'src/main.js',
            // the source template
            template: 'public/index.html',
            // output as dist/index.html
            filename: 'index.html',
            // when using title option,
            // template title tag needs to be <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
            title: 'Index Page',
            // chunks to include on this page, by default includes
            // extracted common chunks and vendor chunks.
            chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
        },
        index2: {
            // entry for the page
            entry: 'src/index2.js',
            // the source template
            template: 'public/index2.html',
            // output as dist/index.html
            filename: 'index2.html',
            // when using title option,
            // template title tag needs to be <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
            title: 'Index2 Page',
            // chunks to include on this page, by default includes
            // extracted common chunks and vendor chunks.
            chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index2']
        },
        // when using the entry-only string format,
        // template is inferred to be `public/subpage.html`
        // and falls back to `public/index.html` if not found.
        // Output filename is inferred to be `subpage.html`.
        //subpage: 'src/subpage/main.js'
    }
}
```

In the Views/Index.cshtml how can I reference the necessary files when the generated files include a hash.  i.e. i need to reference index2.24ba2458.js and chunk-vendors.869468b2.js (as well as the css files)

Can I redirect the output directory for index2.html to /Views/Home/Index2.cshtml?

Is it possible that I can serve a HMR js to an mvc view?

Comment: Hey, I have a similar set up, did you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the filename hashing in the config so that you can reference the js file output to the dist directory.

```
module.exports = {
filenameHashing: false,
```